# How to call prismic.io API from ember.js

Tags: ember.js

Has anybody seen any implementations of Ember.js and prismic.io? Has anybody successfully called the prismic.io API from ember.js?

Answer (score 2):

I believe Qonto is doing this with something they created called ember-prismic-dom. Here is the article: https://medium.com/qonto-way/introducing-ember-prismic-dom-c362647037d7